# How to periodicaly send a list of unresolved alerts from zabbix to telegram?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

How to print only a list of unresolved problems to telegram every hour?

If this list has changed, then delete all entries and write a new updated list of unresolved  problems.
Any ideas how this can be implemented?

Comment: with Zabbix you can make an hourly reminder of each problem, setting steps to 0 in the operation that sends the Telegram message.  https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/notifications/action/operation . Instead, to retrieve all Problems and send a single message, you'll need to write a middleware, querying Zabbix API.